# Is the tag "travel" a little broad?

Tags: discussion, tagging

via [Zach Lipton in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31758867#31758867):

> [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel)
>   why does the travel tag exist?
>   wouldn't that apply to every question here?

Comment: Weird, there aren't any questions tagged with it. How does it exist? I say burn it

Comment: @user568458 that's because they cleaned up the questions

Comment: It's not broad enough. I recommend replacing it with [stuff].

Comment: @hippietrail Please make this an answer so that we can have a competition for getting the most downvotes.

Comment: @Fiksdal: I would but I realized it might still not be broad enough since I expect "stuff" only covers matter and not anti-matter. Maybe I should ask a factoid question to identify a term which covers both matter and antimatter.

Comment: @hippietrail Great idea.

Comment: Didn't see this earlier. Yeah I went through and removed the four questions or so that were tagged "travel" so that it could be auto-deleted. Since people seem to still be trying to use it a bunch, I agree it should be burned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) tag already has zero questions (and strangely, two followers).

This tag is uselessly broad on a site which is *about* travel. It should be blacklisted so that it cannot be used in the future.

Comment: It had about five questions from within the past few months before I removed them the other day. People are going to keep using it unless we blacklist it. Is that something the mods can arrange?

Comment: The moderators can contact the community team to have it blacklisted.

Comment: I just removed this tag from three questions that had it.  What is the process for having the tag blacklisted?

Comment: @AriBrodsky A moderator must ask the community team to have it blacklisted.

Answer (score 10):

The tag is too generic and broad. It doesn't categorise the question into a defined scope. It adds no relevant information whatsoever. Therefore, it should be burned with flames so tall as to make it an example for all other similarly useless generic tags.

Comment: You are correct. We need to more precise tags in place of this poorly thought out one. For the first we need a good word meaning "too generic but not broad enough" and the second meaning "not generic enough and also too broad".

Answer (score 0):

No, it is way too narrow because some questions are not about [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) in the strict sense, but are vaguely travel related. It should be replaced with the [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/question) tag.

As a bonus, it is not only more general, but also a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that we love so much.

Comment: Giving credit where credit is due: this answer was inspired by the comment of @hippietrail

Comment: I sense you have entered the [downvote competition](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/is-the-tag-travel-a-little-broad#comment11397_3836). +1 from me. (Strategic upvoting.)

Comment: @Fiksdal: no hard feeling. I've upvoted your answer for the same reason.

Comment: I should have guessed that you were that strategic. And thanks for officially confirming your entry into the competition :)

Comment: @Fiksdal As a gesture of goodwill, I've given each of you a downvote.

Comment: @reirab Awesome. :)

Comment: It seems we should incarnate at least one tag specific for questions with a tenuous relationship to travel. Your word choice [tag:vaguely-travel-related] should work fine!

Answer (score -5):

As Zach said in the chat:

> If we all work hard, we can work together to add it to all the questions.

It's necessary, IMO.

Comment: We will reconsider it after you successfully get the necessary [programming] tag added to all questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @hippietrail I will personally undertake that endavour.

Comment: I passionately gave you (-1)

Comment: @Ulkoma Thank you. I'm *massively* ahead of hippietrail, he/she hasn't even *submitted* his/her [tag:stuff] suggestion yet.

Comment: +1 Getting all the questions tagged "travel" would be a huge team effort we can all collaborate on, which would be a great boost for site morale. And think how useful it will be: people who don't look at the URL or the site logo will still know this is a travel site.

Comment: @ZachLipton LMAO. Totally agree. And thanks for the upvote! I was about to say "[Noooooooo!](https://youtu.be/WWaLxFIVX1s)" because it will reduce my chances of winning the [downvote competition](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/is-the-tag-travel-a-little-broad/3837?noredirect=1#comment11397_3836) with Hippietrail, but it looks like he/she has chickened out anyway and it looks like I will win on walkover :).

Comment: How are you going to handle posts which already have the maximum of 5 tags?

Comment: @Bernhard Clearly, lots of less useful tags will now have to be removed from questions . We have to make room for tags like [tag:travel], [tag:stuff] and [tag:matter+antimatter].

Comment: [tag:things] is obviously missing in this hierarchy. It belongs right between [tag:travel] and [tag:stuff]. This will get us close to solving Bernhard's well-identified problem as there will now be four worthy tags to put on all questions. Obviously you can now see what the next problem is. But I have the perfect solution for that too. The [tag:questions] tag!

Comment: @hippietrail Excellent, we now have four perfect tags for all questions. [tag:travel],  [tag:stuff], [tag:things], and [tag:questions].

Comment: Five! Tag [tag:matter+antimatter]. I do realize it's currently our second ugliest second most poorly worded tag, but we'll come up with a better tag name later.

Comment: @hippietrail Thanks. Splendid glory awaits us. And I also have to go to Ask Ubuntu and add  [tag:linux] to all the questions there.

Comment: My favourite kind of glory! Bring it on! I shall commence working on my speech.

Comment: We must be careful though. Some off-topic questions here are not actually about travel. These questions should, of course, never be tagged [travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel).

Comment: @ZachLipton Good point, lol.

Comment: Just when I thought our improvements were complete I find I now have to propose [tag:non-travel] to bring the new system to a state of perfection.

Comment: @hippietrail Or maybe [tag:off-topic]? Or you could tag with both [tag:off-topic] and [tag:non-travel] for redundancy, I suppose.

Comment: @reirab LOL, yeah, clearly [tag:non-travel] and [tag:off-topic] should both be created :)

Comment: And for questions where the OP seems nice how about [tag:not-quite-on-topic]?

Comment: @hippietrail Sounds fair enough. We can use tags to welcome new users, too.

Comment: @Fiksdal: [tag:hi]!

Comment: @hippietrail Hahaha. Yes, excellent.

Comment: @Fiksdal [tag:travel], [tag:stuff], [tag:things] and [tag:questions] don't cover everything. We need [tag:concepts], too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby We're getting up to a lot of different tags here, but maybe it's OK. [tag:concepts] seems useful. It can remind readers and OP that the question involves concepts. I've also recently conceived of a tag that should be called [tag:human-travelers], to be used whenever the person traveling is human.

Comment: @Fiksdal Should we add [tag:intergalactic] and [tag:acta] (Alpha Centauri Travel Authorization), for future-proofing?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah, we might as well start creating these tags now. Will have to be done, sooner or later. If OP doesn't specify otherwise, we can assume these tags are appropriate and add them to the question.