# Enough already with [travel]? Time to get it block-listed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

See this related question: [Is the tag “travel” a little broad?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3836). Or more specifically, [its accepted answer by Michael Hampton](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3841):

> The [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) tag already has zero questions (and strangely, two followers).
>
> This tag is uselessly broad on a site which is *about* travel. It should be blacklisted so that it cannot be used in the future.

I noticed [the tag has resurfaced with 5 questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel). As such, I'm posting this as feature request for a CM to add it to [the blocked tag list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tags).

I acknowledge that burination and not using the tag is [the usual solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242661) to prevent tags from being used. Since this site is so focused on travel, I assume the tag will be back even after we remove it form the current questions. In fact, the tag has only recently reappeared after it had been...

> burned with flames so tall as to make it an example for all other similarly useless generic tags.

Source: [JoErNanO♦ in another answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3838)

As such, I think [block-listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocked-tags) is warranted. :)

Comment: " Per-site lists of tags that cannot be created or used. To suggest a tag be blocked, use [tag-block-request] instead. " - you can always suggest it ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo yea I think we're still supposed to ask on the per-site meta (on main meta it might be closed as a one-site issue). This is my way of making the suggestion, I think a mod can add the [status-review] tag and that should put it in the CM queue who can create the tag-block.

Comment: @MarkMayo I agree with JJJ, the Travel Meta is more appropriate to request this.

Comment: Not fussed, as long as [tag:travel] gets removed ;)

Comment: I cannot find [tag:travel] in the list of tags: https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name What's happening?

Comment: @JoErNanO Since I already removed the tag from all the questions, it has been deleted in the meantime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) tag has travelled straight onto the blocklist as an intrinsic tag - users trying to tag a post with the [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) tag will now receive the message:

> The 'travel' tag is not allowed.

Safe travels, everyone.

Comment: Thank you Kyle.

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree with the idea to block-list this tag. I have removed the [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) from the 5 questions mentioned in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

At the cost of quoting myself, I believe:

> [[travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel)] should be burned with flames so tall as to make it an example for all other similarly useless generic tags

Since the blocklisting feature exists (I was honestly not aware of this until right now) let's use it. As per [the current procedure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag), I have asked Community Managers to blocklist [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) on Travel.SE. I am confident we will get notified once this happens.